# How do I have a function repeat after go button is pressed until stop button pressed? (tkinter, python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, loops, time, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that has two buttons "stop" and "go." "go" repeatedly prints "running" every 5 seconds until the button "stop" is pressed. Is this possible to do so in python 2.7 and using tkinter? This is my code so far...

```
from Tkinter import *

class startGo():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.displayMain()    
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def fnCreateWidgets(self):
        self.frWindow = Frame()
        self.frWindow.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.frWindow.update()

    def displayMain(self):
        self.cvOne = Canvas(self.master, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.cvOne.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.frmWindowOne = Frame(self.cvOne)
        self.master.title("StopGo")
        self.master.minsize(100, 100)

        self.frmWindowOne.grid()

        self.frmWindowOne.btnStop = Button(self.frmWindowOne, text="Stop", font=("MagdaCleanMono", 12), command=self.stop)
        self.frmWindowOne.btnStop.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=EW)

        self.frmWindowOne.btnGo = Button(self.frmWindowOne, text="Go", font=("MagdaCleanMono", 12), command=self.go)
        self.frmWindowOne.btnGo.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=EW)

    def go(self):
        #code

    def stop(self):
        #code

root = Tk()
app = startGo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.do_something).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop).pack()

    def do_something(self):
        print("Doing Something")
        self.after_id = self.after(500, self.do_something)

    def stop(self):
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

so when you push start button it calls the function directly

this then calls the after function with itself as the target to be run after 500ms

after the function completes the the script re enters the tkinter mainloop until the time that it gets run again.

to stop the script we cancel the after with the ID that we saved earlier.